# every frame jquery function

Tags: jquery, image, html

I'm trying to make a "live" image preview with jQuery but for now i have only the idea. So the idea is to have a div(100px/100px) and an input form and when you put link there to visualize an image "shrinked" to 100px/100px in the div.But if user don't copy the link exactly and start to type it,the code should check if the link is right to image (for example .../image.jpg) and then to show it. I will make maybe this div to visualize an image with external link with .attr but the whole thing will be hard for me . If anyone want to help , you are welcomed :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple way is not complicated, just one textbox, one placeholder and some jQuery code.

Assuming this is the textbox:

```
<input type="text" id="txtImagePreview" />
```

Have such container for the preview itself:

```
<div id="ImagePlaceHolder"><span class="error">Invalid image URL</span></div>
```

And finally this is the required jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var timer = 0;
    $("#ImagePlaceHolder .error").hide();
    var oPreviewImage = $("<img />");
    oPreviewImage.bind("error", function() {
        $(this).hide();
        $(this).parent().find(".error").show();
    });
    $("#ImagePlaceHolder").append(oPreviewImage);
    oPreviewImage.hide();
    $("#txtImagePreview").bind("keyup paste", function() {
        window.clearTimeout(timer);
        var txtPreview = $(this);
        timer = window.setTimeout(function() {
            $("#ImagePlaceHolder").find(".error").hide();
            var imageURL = txtPreview.val();
            oPreviewImage.attr("src", imageURL);
            oPreviewImage.show();
        }, 500);
    });
});​
```

[Live test case](http://jsfiddle.net/v6EPJ/).

Note that checking for ".jpg" in the URL is pointless, many image URL's don't have any extension for example your gravatar is `http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/b4a2d7e5c786e61fab787097b2d4f27b?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG` as you see there's no way to tell by URL alone if this is image or not.

The logic is simple: assign the given URL into `<img>` and show it inside the placeholder. If the image object `onerror` triggers it means the image is invalid, hide it and optionally show custom friendly message.

Using timer for two reasons:

- The new text is not available right after the `paste` event, so the only way to get the new value is wait a little time.
- When user is typing, no point to assign after each character typed when he's typing fast - let him finish first.

Answer (score 0):

http://cssglobe.com/easiest-tooltip-and-image-preview-using-jquery/

Have you checked the above link